# Slow sqlite EF any statemnbt

Tags: sqlite, entity-framework-6, any

This statement need in EF 6 with Sqlite 5 seconds over the network.

```
dm.Context.Variants.Any(v => v.proID == 3D 
                          && v.varDeleted != 1 
                          && v.varIsLocked == 1);
```

How can I make it faster in der DB Brower for SQLite this query needs 50ms.

```
select * from variant where proID = 3 and varDeleted != 1 and varIsLocked = 1
```

Comment: The two queries are different. `Any()` returns a boolean, not result rows. What does the actual code look like? Why not `db.Context.Variants. Where(...)` ?

Comment: select count(*) from variant where proID = 3 and varDeleted != 1 and varIsLocked = 1 needs 35in the DB Browser. This is much faster and returns and integer instead of boolean.